# Natural feeling Pinch to Zoom in Maui Application

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, maui

I have a pinch to zoom on an image. While it does work, it feels clunky and unnatural, especially when you pan with it. I can not use a pan container with the pinch since my solution uses the single touch for drawing so it has to retain a pinch.

There is pinch container examples all over from Microsoft, and no matter how I tweak it, it never feels like the photo app for iOS.

I have created a repository as an example application.
https://github.com/AustinOberholtzer/MauiPinchZoom

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class PinchContainer : ContentView
{
    private double currentScale = 1;
    private double startScale = 1;
    private double xOffset;
    private double yOffset;

    public PinchContainer()
    {
        var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinchGesture);
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object? sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
        {
            startScale = Content.Scale;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
        }

        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
        {
            // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
            currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
            currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the X pixel coordinate.
            var renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
            var deltaX = renderedX / Width;
            var deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
            var originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
            var renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
            var deltaY = renderedY / Height;
            var deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
            var originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

            // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
            var targetX = xOffset - ((originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale));
            var targetY = yOffset - ((originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale));

            // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
            Content.TranslationX = Math.Clamp(targetX, -Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            Content.TranslationY = Math.Clamp(targetY, -Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

            // Apply scale factor
            Content.Scale = currentScale;
        }

        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
        {
            // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pinchZoom="using:PinchZoom"
             x:Class="PinchZoom.MainPage"
             x:Name="View">

    <Grid
        HorizontalOptions="Fill"
        VerticalOptions="Fill"
        BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=View}}">

        <pinchZoom:PinchContainer
            IsClippedToBounds="True"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

            <Image
                Source="xp.jpg"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

        </pinchZoom:PinchContainer>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Have you tried on a physical device?

Comment: Yes and in release. This is their standard recommended code but it all feels the same.

Comment: Is it better if removing ```IsClippedToBounds```?

Comment: No it makes no difference

Comment: The difference between your sample and official sample is [XAML part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/pinch?view=net-maui-8.0#create-a-pinch-container). Have you tried to simplify your XAML and test  if it is better?